# remove plaintext links from post in php

Tags: php, regex

The question is fairly straight forward. I want to remove text links from posts.

```
$post = $_POST['text'];
//something to remove any instance of a text link
```

Please understand I am not trying to remove

```
<a href="...">text</a>
```

Rather I just want any plaintext links removed

```
This is an example. All this is okay but I want the following stripped:
http://someurl.com/... or http://www.someurl.com/...
```

Here is what I have been trying:

```
    $post = preg_replace(@^(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*$@i, '', $posted);
```

I am getting error: unexpected '^', if I remove the ^ then I get an unexpected ':' error.

Comment: post your code, your attempts and some sample data

Comment: Try this regex [**`("[^"]+"|'[^']+')(*SKIP)(*F)|https?://(?:www\.)?(?:[^/ ]+/?)+`**](https://regex101.com/r/lA0yP3/1) - [PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/1SW3H)